# Refresh bootstrap-datepicker after page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application with a vertical navigation bar and a main page. On the navbar there is a [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker):

```
@using Mattinale.Domain.Entities
@using Mattinale.WebUI.Models
@model MattinaleViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendarioMattinale').datepicker({
            todayBtn: "linked",
            language: "it",
            todayHighlight: true
        })
    });
</script>
```

By selecting any date on the datepicker, an action method on the main page controller is called by routing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendarioMattinale').on('changeDate', function (e) {
        anno = e.date.getYear() + 1900;
        mese = e.date.getMonth() + 1;
        giorno = e.date.getDate();
        window.location.href = '/' + anno + '/' + mese + '/' + giorno;
    })
});
```

The problem is that when the page is loaded, the selection on the newly selected date is cleared. I've tried to modify the initialization script by adding an update method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendarioMattinale').datepicker({
        todayBtn: "linked",
        language: "it",
        todayHighlight: true
    })
    dataSelezionata = @Model.GetDataSelezionata();
    $('#calendarioMattinale').datepicker('update', dataSelezionata);
});
```

but now the controller doesn't even get initialized.

Thanks,
Davide.

Comment: Are you want to assign new value while datepicker is reloaded? Does `calendarioMattinale` element created from HTML helper? Your problem still a little bit unclear in certain points, especially in `window.location.href = '/' + anno + '/' + mese + '/' + giorno` which deviates from standard MVC routing.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto calendarioMattinale element is an empty div element that gets populated by the $('#calendarioMattinale').datepicker({...}) function - these are the bootstrap-datepicker guidelines on initializing such element. As for the routing, that allows me to call the Index(int anno = 0, int mese = 0, int giorno = 0) action on the main page's controller. You select a date, that date is passed to the action controller that shows data from a database filtered by that date value.